# Why can't I see the "value" column in SYS.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security

I have some extended property column descriptions in a SQL Server 2008 database, and when I login to management studio and do a simple query:

```
Select * from SYS.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES;
```

I can see all the columns in that table, including the extended property "value" column.

When I have an ASP.NET page login to the db, perform that query, and then bind it to a GridView, it can select everything BUT the "value" column.

Is there some special permission my ASP db user needs to see the value column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'value' column uses the sql_variant data type which may be causing the problem...but I can't replicate this. Is the app using the same credentials as you're using in Management Studio.

Comment: No, different user, which is why I'm thinking my app user does not have some special permission?  App user is dbwriter and dbreader, while my Management Studio user has db_owner permissions...

Comment: It was the sql_variant type causing the issue.  I just did a CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),value) on the select and it shows up in the GridView just fine.  Thanks!